# How to downgrade Ubuntu 18.10 to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, vps, ubuntu-14.04

My VPS host doesn't have any options for this and the script I'm trying to run absolutely only works on Ubuntu 14.04, any options? i prepaid for the VPS so i don't wanna have to switch hosts.

Comment: If its a script it would likely be easier to fix the script then downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the script to work on a supported OS, like a newer Ubuntu. 14.04 is end of support. Buying Extended Security Maintenance through Ubuntu Advantage keeps the base OS secure for a little longer, but is not a long-term solution.

---

In general, downgrades are restores from backup, or creating new instances on the old version. Very little is forward compatible enough to allow un-converting configs and data from the new version to the old.